# Should I use Google Maps degug or release key whenever setting up a beta/alpha test

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-api-console

So I will be setting up my first alpha test. Do I need to use the release key or debug key that created for the Google Maps API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a release key for that. Since this is an alpha RELEASE of your app. Meaning it will be used by others.

You can configure it in build.gradle in a very elegant way.